# Flink classloader falis when deploy the Job in cluster

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am observing a very strange behavior in flink job deployment.

When I run the Job in eclipse. It runs the job without any issues.

When I run the same job in Flink cluster it fails. I am using the following command to run the job.

> ./flink run --class FlinkKafkaExample flink-streaming-confluent-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar  --inputTopic1 sample-data-topic1 --inputTopic2 sample-data-topic2 --env example.properties

I am getting the following error.

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/avro/generic/GenericData$Array
        at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.utils.AvroKryoSerializerUtils.addAvroGenericDataArrayRegistration(AvroKryoSerializerUtils.java:64)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.buildKryoRegistrations(KryoSerializer.java:564)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.<init>(KryoSerializer.java:132)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.GenericTypeInfo.createSerializer(GenericTypeInfo.java:90)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraph.addOperator(StreamGraph.java:202)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraph.addSource(StreamGraph.java:170)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator.transformSource(StreamGraphGenerator.java:470)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator.transform(StreamGraphGenerator.java:170)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator.transformOneInputTransform(StreamGraphGenerator.java:527)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator.transform(StreamGraphGenerator.java:166)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator.generateInternal(StreamGraphGenerator.java:132)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator.generate(StreamGraphGenerator.java:124)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.getStreamGraph(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1538)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:53)
        at FlinkKafkaExample.main(FlinkKafkaExample.java:127)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:528)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:420)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:404)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:781)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.runProgram(CliFrontend.java:275)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:210)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1020)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$9(CliFrontend.java:1096)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:30)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1096)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Array
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 29 more
```

When I check the dependencies required for the Jar its available in the classpath. I have even tried adding the same jar in the lib folder of flink 1.5.0

Dependency its looking for is as shown below:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-avro -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Could you check whether `org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Array` is contained in `flink-streaming-confluent-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar`?

Comment: @TillRohrmann I have checked the Jar containing class is already inside the flink-streaming-confluent-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar. This code works fine when I deploy in flink 1.4 but  when I deploy this in flink cluster running version 1.5 is giving the issue. I have changed the pom.xml for version 1.5 and works well when I run it from eclipse.